# jQuery and HTML 5 Routing by Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url-routing

I am trying to build my first single page app using jQuery. My strategy is to have 1 large HTML file that describes what content should go on each "page" (screen/URL/route), 1 large CSS file that handles layout and styling, and 1+ JS files where all business logic, event handlers, data population, etc. resides.

Here's my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Omitted for brevity. -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HTML for the home "page" at myapp.example.com. -->
        <div id="homepage">
            <!-- Etc. -->
        </div>

        <!-- HTML for the about "page" at myapp.example.com/about. -->
        <div id="about">
            <!-- Etc. -->
        </div>

        <!-- HTML for the login "page" at myapp.example.com/login. -->
        <div id="login">
            <!-- Etc. -->
        </div>

        <!-- HTML for all other "pages". -->
        <!-- ...etc. -->

        <!-- Load the main JS file. -->
        <script src="maypp.js" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I guess the idea here is that the entire DOM will be downloaded but only 1 "page" (`div`) will be visible/displayed at any given time.

My problem:

1. Is this a standard way of implementing SPAs in jQuery? Or does jQuery (or any plugin or jQuery-compatible lib/framework) offer a better way to accomplish a big, single, all-at-once upfront download?
2. Assuming I'm more or less on target, how can I set up routing so that the `myapp.js` file inspects the requested URL and determines which "page" to make visible? I say "routing" here because I'd like to leverage a true router here, with built-in HTML 5 history management (back/forward buttons). **Code/pseudo-code examples much appreciated.**

Comment: Funnily enough, I am working on a SPA Javscript framework at the moment.  I'm not going to suggest that (it's very early days and I'm not here to promote myself), but I will suggest looking at `location.hash` and `$(window).on("hashchange")`.  Make all your links something like `href='#hompage'` and you're virtually done.

Comment: I forgot to mention - for back/forward handling, simply keep an array of page IDs as you change the view.

Comment: Using hash is a good way to implement SPA. The state of you app is represented in the hash. Meanwhile, checkout these jquery libs until Archer's lib is ready.
[jquery.address](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address) or [jquery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)